# How can I perform time series data analysis and compare similarities in trends?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I am trying to prove that CRP (protein in your blood) will be serially raised after an  esophagectomy regardless of whether you have a post operative infection/complication due to the surgery (which is currently relied on as a primary indicator of such). How could I show this statistically? What kind of analysis should I do? Any help would be much appreciated

This is a comparison of the daily mean post op CRP levels of 60 people. The blue line is those who have no post op complications and the orange line is those who do.

[image]